# Apache2 Reverse Proxy - different handling or urls

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, proxypass

I struggling with a reverse proxy configuration and specific rewriting/proxypass depending on URL-path.

Szenario:

- Reverse Proxy in DMZ
- SSL ends on Reverse Proxy
- Requests should be passed to internal server via http
- HTTP needs to be rewritten to HTTPS
- In html hrefs are build like "/system/js/abc.js"

My current config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.customer.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://media.customer.com$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName media.customer.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/customer.com/

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.crt

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://serverName/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://serverName/

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://serverName/ /
</VirtualHost>
```

That would not be a huge problem, but we need to get following rules working:

1. Only base-url "Http(s)://serverName" is routed to http://serverName/system/ (add /system/) to base-URL
2. Every deeper URL only protocol changes from http to https. No change to URL.
3. Absolute http-URLs need to changes to https-URLs

The above config works for:

- [http]/serverName/system/
- [http]/serverName/system
- [https]/serverName/system/
- [https]/serverName/system
- [http]/serverName/system/img/test.gif
- [https]/serverName/system/img/test.gif

Do I put "/fotoweb/" in RewriteRule or ProxyPass, we get doubled strings like:
http://serverName/system/system/img/test.gif

For my opinion, I need to identify if its a base-url and then add "/system/", otherwise just map to http. But no clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This rewrites all that is not HTTPS to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Not sure what you consider 'base-url', but I'm assuming it's HTTPS + not starting with
'/system'. This rewrites all that doesn't start with '/system' to '/system/...':

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/system
RewriteRule .* /system%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If it's just '/', then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /system/ [R=301,L]
```

All in one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.customer.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName media.customer.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/system
    RewriteRule .* /system%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/customer.com/

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.crt

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://serverName/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://serverName/

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://serverName/ /
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks fuero! I Updated the Description regarding base url. So the logic we want needs to be done by rewrite rule, not proxypass. There we cannot define regex for Url matching

Comment: Look close: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` - doesn't that do what you ask?